# Reducing problems to solve easier problems

Tags: np-complete, reductions, np-hard, np

Is there any instance where a problem $A$ can be reduced to a problem $B$ where $B$ is easier to solve than $A$?

I've been learning about NP-Hardness recently and seems that the answer is no. Whenever we show $ A \leq_p B$ its also said that $B$ must therefore be at least as hard as $A$. If this is always the case then is reducing a problem into another only useful for proving NP-Hardness/NP-Completeness? Is there no way to leverage reductions to find an easier problem to solve than the one you originally start out with?

Comment: In many cases, taking the dual of a problem results in a different problem that is much easier to solve.  Is that the kind of thing you were thinking of? (E.g. [optimization - What are the advantages of studying the dual problem in linear programming? - Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243706/what-are-the-advantages-of-studying-the-dual-problem-in-linear-programming).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roughly speaking, no.  One way to solve A is by using the method for solving B combined with the reduction from A to B.  So if that reduction is efficient, then solving A can't be too much harder than solving B.

If I'm pedantic, yes, B might be a little bit easier to solve than A.  If the reduction is very expensive (takes a long time, or significantly increases the size of the problem instance), then B might be a lot easier to solve than A.  Normally in study of NP-completeness we address this by requiring the reduction to run in polynomial time, and we ignore any differences that are at most a polynomial factor.